# How can i keep user previous data intact for system app if android:sharedUserId is changed?

Tags: android, ota, android-backup-service, custom-rom, android-firmware

I have a custom rom where i included an application as system app that has no [android:sharedUserId](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#uid) declared in manifest. Recently i added some new features for which i need to use **android:sharedUserId**. As a result while applying update it results in failure. Because of being system app it can not be uninstalled. I also try to install over **adb** and it results in **INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE**.
So as a work around i planned to place the update as a patch of firmware update(OTA). This time it can install the updated version which has **android:sharedUserId** declared in manifest.
But the problem is system deletes all the data of previous version and treat the update as a fresh installation.

So my questions are as follows:

1. Is it possible to preserve previous app data?
2. Is there any tweeks that can apply to firmware source code so that it doesn't deleted previous data?
3. Is there any way i can backup those data and restore it after firmware update complete?

**Note:** Here data includes shared preference, sqlite data, other files like image/audio/txt etc.

Comment: "Recently i added some new features for which i need to use android:sharedUserId." -- `android:sharedUserId` is deprecated. Are you sure that you want to use it?

Comment: Yes i know that. But since it is custom rom and the device is specialised. So i don't care about it. @CommonsWare

Comment: Note that you may have better luck asking your question on sites specializing in custom ROMs, such as XDA's forums. Stack Overflow is stronger for ordinary app development.